# How to get data from table row using jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlconnection, tablerow, mssql-jdbc

I want to set my Combobox items to get data from the database table's row in a single string with JDBC. On my database table, there are three columns but each row matches every item for my Combobox.

Comment: Please explain more of what you are trying to do and please provide the code of the problem you are facing. It will help you and everyone here...

Comment: Cmpiler v2 thanks for your attention. I have a JCombobox on the form and a table on my SQL database. I want to get datas from the table to set the items of the combobox. My table has 3 column [id] [index] [placename] and i want to set my Jcombobox items like that [id index placename]. Second item of my Jcombobox value will be second row of my table.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
public Object komboAddedbitems(){
    try {
        Connect.conn();
   PreparedStatement ps=Connect.qoshul().prepareStatement("select * from MyTable");
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        int i=0;
          while(rs.next())
          { 
              JComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("indeks")+rs.getString("placename"));
          }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```